# JFreeChart: How to define a DataSet that groups by year, month and day?

Tags: database, jpa, jfreechart

I have a SQL query already that gets the data I need but I'm struggling to figure out how to get that into a chart. This is sample data as result of my query:

```
year    month   day mode    amount  duration
2013    2   22  0   1   36001
2013    7   7   1   1   55062
2015    12  23  1   6   13
2015    12  23  4   4   11
2015    12  23  7   31  104
2015    12  23  8   2   4
2015    12  23  12  11  21
2015    12  23  13  3   8
2016    3   24  1   207 519
```

If I wanted to graph lets say amount grouped per year, month and day how would that be done in JFreeChart?

Comment: Try `JDBCXYDataset`.

Comment: Some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20JDBCXYDataset).